# Configurating External Accessory with bound rate - interpreting output stream

Tags: swift, swift3

I've got a connection with a hardware which returns after every 10 seconds data. Returned data is not telling me anything, how could I interprete it ?

**EDIT**

Opening Accessory :

```
public func openAccessory() {
        let _accessories = getConnectedAccessories()
        var _accessory: EAAccessory?

        for acsy in _accessories {
            if acsy.protocolStrings.contains("com.protocol.link") {
                _accessory = acsy
            }
        }
        if _accessory != nil {
            let session = EASession(accessory: _accessory!, forProtocol: "com.protocol.link")
            if session != nil {
                guard let inputStream2 = session?.inputStream else {
                    return
                }
                inputStream2.delegate = self
                inputStream2.schedule(in: .current, forMode: .defaultRunLoopMode)
                inputStream = inputStream2
                inputStream.open()
                session?.outputStream?.delegate = self
                session?.outputStream?.schedule(in: .current, forMode: .defaultRunLoopMode)
                session?.outputStream?.open()
            }
        }
    }
```

Reading stream :

```
func stream(_ aStream: Stream, handle eventCode: Stream.Event) {
        switch eventCode{
        case Stream.Event.hasBytesAvailable:
            if (aStream == inputStream) {
                var buffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: 9)
                while (inputStream.hasBytesAvailable) {
                    let bytesRead: Int = inputStream.read(&buffer, maxLength: buffer.count)
                    if bytesRead > 0 {
                        let data = Data(bytes: buffer)
                        let answer = String.init(data: data, encoding: .ascii)
                        print(answer ?? "")
                    }
                }
            }
        default:
            print("No bytes available")
        }
    }
```

I've got still the same output :

```
2017-09-14 12:53:49.612822+0200 extDemo[7456:2344109] refreshPreferences: HangTracerEnabled: 1
2017-09-14 12:53:49.613059+0200 extDemo[7456:2344109] refreshPreferences: HangTracerDuration: 500
2017-09-14 12:53:49.613211+0200 extDemo[7456:2344109] refreshPreferences: ActivationLoggingEnabled: 0 ActivationLoggingTaskedOffByDA:0
2017-09-14 12:53:51.343255+0200 extDemo[7456:2344109] eaAccessory CoreAccessoryPrimaryUUID = 467AAB42-8EDD-4256-A0B2-ECFCDB99D986
connected right accessory to the phone
2017-09-14 12:53:51.361954+0200 extDemo[7456:2344109] accessoryd sessionResult = 1, useSocketInterace = 0, sessionID = 0xD
No bytes available
No bytes available
No bytes available
«ÍÕ
«ÍÕ«Í"¦a@ø
«Íbâaþ
«Íbâaþ
«ÍÕ«Í1âéþ
«Í"¦a@ø«Í"¦a@ø
«Íbâaþ
«ÍÕ\246
«Í"¦a@ø
«ÍÕ
«Í"¦öóþ
«ÍÕ\242@æ
«Í"¦a@ø
«Íª1ñ´þ
«Íbâaþ«Í"¦öóþ
```

But got some extra informations:

1. Bound rate to 115200 - I know how to set it via putty and the recived message is as it's supposed to be.
2. After I make a connection with my link ( com.protocol.link ) it is a cable via which I conect with `LMU` I need to configure the proper parameters (23 bytes):

   {0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0xC2, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3E, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01}
3. I found [Guide](https://www.google.pl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwjBtaSmzqTWAhXFK5oKHUIBCNEQFgg6MAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmarketplace.thingworx.com%2F-%2Fmedia%2FMarketplace%2FDownload%2520Item%2FRelated%2520Content%2FC%2FCalAmp-LMU-Series-Setup-Guide.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFDwCsAFCMEuCMvp_ek48LVOXyQsQ) for LMU - they saying that I need to use socket port and UDP protocol, but I already got a connection with a device, but recived message is not that as I excepted.
   Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the hardware that you are talking about? input you get might not be string or it might be string in another encoding.

Comment: @Sweeper LMU 4232 CalAmp

Comment: @Sweeper Could u have a look on an update? Thanks!

Comment: You need to read the documentation if available, or it's just reverse-engineering, and we won't be much of a help. I guess there is a "Start of Message, Some Headers?, Info Message, End Of Message".

Comment: @Larme I see, do you know how could I set bound rate ?